# How do I send a table cell's id to the onclick function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am creating an HTML table dynamically and each cell has an id. I want to send the cell.id to the onclick function, but I am not sure how to do it.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  myFunction();
}

function myFunction() {
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell1.id = 'a'
  cell2.id = 'b'
  cell1.innerHTML = "cell1";
  cell2.innerHTML = "cell2";
  cell1.onclick = xfunc(cell1.id);
  cell2.onclick = xfunc(cell2.id);
}

function xfunc(id) {
  console.log('click', id)
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable"></table>
```

Using this code the function xfunc does not seem to be called.

On the other hand if I use

```
cell1.onclick=xfunc;
```

The function is called, but of course, I have no cell.id. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually invoking the function the way you have it now. There are a couple of ways to properly call the function onclick. The first using addEventListener and the second uses an anonymous function.

**addEventListener:**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  myFunction();
}

function myFunction() {
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell1.id = 'a'
  cell2.id = 'b'
  cell1.innerHTML = "cell1";
  cell2.innerHTML = "cell2";
  cell1.addEventListener('click', xfunc, false);
  cell2.addEventListener('click', xfunc, false);
}

function xfunc(evt) {
  console.log('click', evt.currentTarget.id)
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable"></table>
```

**Anonymous function:**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  myFunction();
}

function myFunction() {
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell1.id = 'a'
  cell2.id = 'b'
  cell1.innerHTML = "cell1";
  cell2.innerHTML = "cell2";
  cell1.onclick = function(){xfunc(cell1.id)};
  cell2.onclick = function(){xfunc(cell2.id)};
}

function xfunc(id) {
  console.log('click', id)
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable"></table>
```